# What was the first intelligent digital robot?

Tags: history, robotics

Robots have a long history from the (not so) simple mechanical creations of [antiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_of_Alexandria#Inventions) up to today's [fully autonomous models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXxrmussq4E).  The earliest ones could only carry out scripted actions, modern ones adapt to their environments.  Where was this line crossed?  What is the earliest example of an intelligent digital robot?

The criteria:

- **Must make decisions**
  The system must do more than blindly follow prescripted actions.
- **Digital control system**
  The control logic must be fully digital (though not necessarily binary).
- **Must be intelligent**
  Must use "advanced" methods of decision-making.  This should be something more complex than simply-connected logic gates, lookup tables or [cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton)<sup>1</sup>.
- **Must be fully autonomous**
  Remote controlled vehicles, [waldos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_manipulator), fly-by-wire, and the like are excluded.  Rough guidance (e.g. "go to such and such waypoint" or "flip over each widget passing by on the assembly line") is permitted but the robot should do more than blindly perform an action.  The control logic can be external to the robot (e.g. on a cable-connected minicomputer) but should take only very limited human input.
- **Have at least two sensors**
  An array of sensors (e.g. a CCD camera) counts as multiple sensors.
- **Must control at least two independent actuators**
  Simply turning something on and off like a thermostat doesn't count.  A robot with two independently controlled wheel motors does count.
- **Must be "robot-like"**
  It must be capable of moving through its environment in some fashion.  This includes autonomous vehicles, industrial robot arms, etc.  It does not include thermostats, [PLCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) on an assembly line, etc.
- **Not a simulator**
  It must do something productive: e.g. move through its environment, identify and pick something up, etc.  Full-motion flight sims and their ilk are excluded.
- **Not a weapon**
  No missiles and the like (because I said so).

I suspect the answer is something not much more interesting than a thermostat but who knows.  What was the earliest intelligent digital robot?

---

<sup>1</sup> Cellular automata might be permitted if you can make a good case for it.

To potential down-voters: If you feel this question is e.g. too broad, please explain why in the comments below.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any *intelligent* robot around even today.

Comment: Damn, Tofro, I had to restain me so hard not writing this and now it's there :))

Comment: @tofro Quite true; hence my defining it :^)

Comment: Except the definition is rather unclear, vague and contradicting. a) A script containing a switch according to some source is still scripted b) what's wrong with analogue c) advanced is marketing blurb d) - e) Vague, is a switch with three setings also an array? f) what makes two actors more inteligent than one? g) vague, after all, even a thermostat moves in its environment h) Come on, a full motion flight simulator is one of the most complex robot systems. i) unneccessary, but works for me :))

Comment: @Raffzahn I tried to focus the question and make it non-opinion based.  Per the question:  a) a conditional makes it non-scripted. b) nothing wrong with analogue control systems, just focusing on digital. c) true, but if it's too complex for a practical LUT then it's "advanced" e) no, that's a single input that takes one of three values f) actuator, not actor; an actuator is a motor, servo, piston, etc. Two-degrees of freedom is the minimum needed to navigate through a (2D) environment. g) OK, that does have a bit of opinion.  h) Arbitrary, yes as is i) but still definable.

Comment: Focus is good, but if it's arbitary, then the result is rather worthless. a)not clear b) arbitary c) All a turing machien is is a LUT, and it's proven to be universal, isn't it? Therefore c is cotradicting your definition of a e) It's two lines. Logicaly, this would make a CCD a single sensor - deilvering a complex value f) Acutators are **not** restricted to motors. Anything from a coil to a hydraulic does fit. h) and arbitary again damages the value of the result. We need to try harder to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Now we're getting heavy into philosophy.  It could be argued that *any* system can be modeled by a sufficiently large LUT, even if it might take more atoms/particles to construct than exist in the entire universe. e) A sensor is anything that takes a single input and outputs a single (possibly numeric) value.  f) Correct, I thought you'd misread the word.  h) Meaningful answers or too-broad a question? :^)

Comment: _"Meaningful answers or too-broad a question?"_ Well, yeah, too broad may also be a good description - too road and at the same time too restricted. Also, a LUT doesn't have to be very big to create extreme complex systems. (On a side note, I still like to use LUTs to cover complex logic in a few lines of source and even less asembly instructions. They are an awesome tool to manage incredible complex combinations).

Comment: @Raffzahn Agreed. LUTs have their place and are very powerful tools.  Also, as I'm sure you know, a LUT burned into a ROM can often replace dozens of 74-series ICs or an FPGA.

Comment: FPGA and TTL are different issues, as FPGA are themself already a collection of LUTs. And While of course any LUT can be replaced by a number of gates, an fairly simple 8x8 LUT can already require a multitude of basic 74xx gates (measured in transistors) for replacements. I think it is even proven for smaler ones than 8x8. LUTs are as well in hard as in software an incredible tool to reduce implementation effort (less RAM or gates and computing/signaling time)

Comment: The question currently has a score of -1.  Well that was a failed experiment.

Comment: btw at least 2 actuators may be rather restrictive some pretty modern bots got just "one" actuator ... like [rotundus](http://www.rotundus.se) an interesting solution for hermetically sealed platform ... good enough even for sand ...

Comment: @Spektre Actually the robot you linked to *does* have multiple actuators, they're just hermetically sealed inside the outer sphere.  From the four color glossies though it sounds more like a drone than an autonomous robot.  Interesting find though.

Comment: @AlexHajnal may be now but in the past when they start it it got just single actuator that positioned a weight in front of wanted movement  and the globe rotate while the weight falls gravitationally towards it ... And it was not a find really as I was called as a consultant during their article review then ...

Comment: @AlexHajnal real autonomous behavior is usual for stuff like **radio active space scouts** and **soccer bots** (but for the latter you might redefine the autonomous therm a bit as they usually have a distributed/external control system but still no human interaction)... majority of the other bots are just tele-operators and "inteligent" is just a commercial world. For hobby bots there are robo contests to find a way in maze ... there are considered autonomous too and where here for quite some while. There are also the american anual autonomous car races (not sure how they called)

Answer (score 5):

I think the first robot to meet your criteria is [Shakey the robot](http://www.ai.sri.com/shakey/), developed between 1966 and 1972 at the Stanford Research Institute:

- it could make decisions (it included a planner, and could break down complex commands into individual steps on its own);
- its control logic was digital, running initially on a SDS-940 computer, later replaced by a PDP-10;
- as mentioned above, it used a planner; it was also an early adopter of route planning, and led to the development of the A* search algorithm;
- it was autonomous: once given its high-level instructions, it would construct a plan and execute it autonomously, building its own model of its environment;
- it had multiple sensors, including at least a camera, range finder, and bump sensors;
- it could navigate, so it must have had at least two independently-controlled motors;
- it could move through its environment;
- it was not a simulator;
- it was not a weapon.

Another interesting pair of robots of similar vintage are [Freddy and Freddy II](http://www.aiai.ed.ac.uk/project/freddy/), developed from 1969 to 1976 at Edinburgh University; in particular, Freddy II had an actuator arm which it could use to assemble models from component parts.

Comment: If the control logic ran on a PDP-10, then I don't assume the PDP-10 moved around with the robot, so wouldn't this exclude Shakey as "not fully autonomous" as required by the question? (Not that I think that this is a very good criterion for "first", after all waiting until the controlling computer is small enough that it can move around is incidental to developing such a robot). Nor sure about the size of the SDS-940, but I don't think the "camera control unit" in the picture is the complete SDS-940.

Comment: @dirkt I took “autonomous” here to mean that the robot didn’t need any *human* input other than its initial instructions (as opposed to the “remote controlled vehicles, waldos, fly-by-wire” mentioned in the question). Neither Shakey nor Freddy would qualify if they had to be “small” self-sufficient units — they both had controlling computers separate from the robot’s body.

Comment: @dirkt When I said "fully autonomous" I was referring to decision-making, not mobility.  Things like fixed-base robot arms are permitted.

Comment: @StephenKitt Spot on

Comment: Also, "fully autonomous" could be interpreted to cover a much wider degree...no reliance on external power, able to maintain itself... I guess that would be Tesla's "Atomic Robo" - which is, unfortunately, entirely fictional. (http://www.atomic-robo.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The word "intelligent" makes this a philosophical question. Here's one possible answer: scientists mapped out the brain of a worm and in 2014 they recreated it digitally and [put it into a fully autonomous robot](https://singularityhub.com/2014/12/15/worm-brain-simulation-drives-lego-robot/amp) as part of the OpenWorm project. They didn't even have to teach it or give it any instructions.

Answer (score 1):

[Stephen's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8318/6659) is already a good good one, at least when viewed by today's nomenclature. As usual, there's a grey area before such a clear point, one somewhere between the first, completely analogue versions of [Elmer and Elsie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmer_and_Elsie_(robots)) or [Wiener's Palomilla](http://cyberneticzoo.com/cyberneticanimals/1949-wieners-moth-wiener-wiesner-singleton/), and [Shakey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakey_the_robot), the modern style robot.

Some good candidates may be "[La Tortue Cybernetique](http://cyberneticzoo.com/cyberneticanimals/1954-la-tortue-tortoise-amouriq-french/)" of 1951 by Paul-Alain or Zemanek's (*1) "[Vienna Turtle](http://cyberneticzoo.com/cyberneticanimals/1954-vienna-turtle-eichler-zemanek-austrian/)" of 1954, as both control their machinery with relays, and thus binary decisions. Both (and Wiener as well) are influenced by W. Grey Walter's Elmer and Elsie turtles, but changed the implementation away from completely analogue circuitry.

Long story short, it may be a good idea to lighten up this grey area to find a satisfying answer.

---

*1 - [Zemanek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_Zemanek) is a quite important figure in computing history, not least through his lead of the [Mailüfterl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail%C3%BCfterl) project.