# What is generally accepted as being the first machine implementation of a search tree?

Tags: history, robotics

What is generally accepted as being the first machine implementation of a search tree (as they are more commonly known and used in modern computing for things like solving or powering, mazes, checkers, chess, tic-tac-toe, etc.)?

- Early maze solving robots/machines, some of them may have been based on right or left hand rule, and depth search.
- The first machines that played board games,  since obviously each square of the board would have been a permanent part of the machine. (a permanent search tree).
- Obviously, very few of the first maze solvers would have stored the maze, or what they had so far mapped of the maze, however, I suspect that the robot arm built by 'Thomas Ross' in 1933, at the 'University of Washington' would have, it used a type of electromechanical memory .
- Here's a [link to what seem to be the first maze solvers](http://www.joostrekveld.net/?p=290),  'Thomas Ross', at the 'University of Washington', built some (how many?)  at that time.
- I re worded this question, by using the suggestion in the comment below, so I just copied the text in that comment "the first machine implementation of a search tree", to be the question.
- **Note** - I have not actually made it a requisite that the tree or part of it be stored, I just left that undecided to allow 'interesting' other designs to be posted. My unavoidable error is in mentioning storage of the search-tree or how much of it had been generated so far. To make this question truly correct, maybe I should make it a requisite that the search-tree or how much of it had been generated so far, be stored. I think it's wiser to leave it as it is, unless it makes this question too badly asked.

Comment: Do you have an example of one of these 1930s systems?

Comment: 'Thomas Ross', at the 'University of Washington', built some ( how many ? ) at that time,  possibly the first he built was an arm that pointed out the solution, here's a link http://www.joostrekveld.net/?p=290

Comment: A 'search tree' is an abstract concept, and thus any algorithm was likely invented/discovered before anyone built a robot capable of implementing the algorithm.  But maybe I'm just unclear on what you mean by an 'occurrence' of a search tree.

Comment: @another-dave, good point, maybe I will have to add  "have been the first 'occurrence' of search trees as they are more commonly known and used in modern computing for things like solving or powering, checkers,  tic-tac-toe, etc,   since that's what I am intending to mean,  admittedly, your comment may invalidate my question,

Comment: Related: [What was the first intelligent digital robot?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8317/what-was-the-first-intelligent-digital-robot) (my first question on this site IIRC)

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for the first machine implementation of a search tree, as distinct from the abstract algorithm.

Comment: @another-dave  - please feel free to edit my question to say that, if it is required to make the question more valid etc,,  and by machine I assume machine always covers mechanical, electromechanical, and electronic

Comment: For simply-connected mazes (those with only branches/exit not on an isolated island) one can simply use wall-following.  Just pick a wall (e.g. the left-hand one) and keep following it and it will lead to the exit.  IIRC that's how Thomas Ross's robots worked.  His robots used analog circuits (capacitors, mechanical switches, etc.) for decision-making.  The idea was to try to emulate how a real animal's brain works, albeit in a very rudimentary form.

Comment: @AlexHajnal correct assumption of wall following being a valid answer gives me the feeling of this question being fundamental to broad to generate useful answer - only meandering discussion, which the question itself already starts to show with all its additions. _(On a side note, noughts and crosses has been implemented in 1952 as [OXO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OXO_(video_game)) for the EDSAC)_

Comment: I have now drastically simplified the question, and it now asks "What is generally accepted as being the first machine implementation of a search tree", which is what I am trying to determine in this question.  The question now also mentions the first machines that played board games. So I have now removed the emphasis on maze-solvers,  but still mentioned them in the question.

Comment: A problem I have for improving this question is If or not to require that the machine store the search-tree ( or how much they generated so far ), my guess is that it should, I'm not sure.

Comment: Re noughts and crosses: when I was young (I'd guess 10 or 11), a friend's father had built a noughts and crosses machine out of, as far as I know, switches, lights, and relays. No "electronics" in there.

Comment: I suspect that the robot arm built by 'Thomas Ross' in 1933, at the 'University of Washington', either, used 'No Electronics Or Relays', or could have been designed to use 'No Electronics Or Relays', you just plug in the wall-panels to form the maze, and the individual plugs of the panels activate switches which either make, or, disconnect electrical connections, so when you plug in the last panel, the robot arm immediately knew the correct path, probably extremely simple, this is relevant to question - 18292

Comment: The robot arm possesses memory, which I find hard to imagine without some electromechanical component. [This schematic](http://cyberneticzoo.com/mazesolvers/1933-maze-learning-machine-thomas-ross-american/) shows details. I would say that the coil-and-ball constitutes a relay.  I think the panels that make the maze are passive. There is a link [Scientific American article](http://cyberneticzoo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/TRoss_SciAm1933.pdf) which I have not yet read.

Comment: So the question would be, could the robot arm built by 'Thomas Ross' in 1933 have been designed to use 'No Electronics Or Relays', you just plug in the wall-panels to form the maze, and the individual plugs of the panels activate switches which either make, or, disconnect electrical connections, so when you plug in the last panel, the robot arm would immediately know the correct path, like in the concept mentioned in question - 18292

Comment: If the maze tells the robot which way to go via some signalling mechanism, then it's no longer a maze.  Imagine a [hedge maze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampton_Court_Maze) where every junction had a sign telling you which route to take.

Comment: yes, like some hypothetical arcade machine of those days, that would have given the illusion of solving the maze, when in fact it did not, unlike this robotic arm by 'Thomas Ross', which it seems did in fact solve the maze without that type of cheating

Answer (score 5):

Those "what was the first" questions are always difficult, because they assume that somehow the concept sprang suddenly into existence. That's almost never the case, usually the concept is developed gradually, until you reach an abstraction like "search tree" that is then taught in CS.

> for things like solving or powering, mazes

Mazes were solved much earlier without search trees, by using a variant of the "left-hand wall" algorithm, and implement in robots like the ["turtle"](http://www.joostrekveld.net/?p=290) by Thomas Ross mentioned in the comments (I build one of those when I was a kid, with help from my father).

> checkers, chess, tic-tac-toe

There were implementations that did this without search trees, e.g. 80s chess/tic-tac-toe game machines, and probably earlier ones as well. "The first machines that played board games", whatever it was, also most certainly did not use a search tree.

---

For an actual implementation of search trees, you need either backtracking, so a sufficiently "fast" computer, or enough memory. That narrows down the possible window for early implementations.

And while I cannot tell you "the first", a pretty famous implementation of AI using backtracking was [SHRDLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHRDLU) (1968-70), a natural language parser for a "toy block" world with a planner to execute actions in this world. The [Planner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHRDLU) used backtracking.

So that was already a pretty elaborate implementation.

The [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which is one of the first practical ones to actually use backtracking/search trees to solve game playing was published in 1968, which gives another hint of the timeline.

Finally, [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) was sort of a natural language to express these kinds of algorithms. It was specified in 1958, so that gives another indication of the timeline.

So I'd assume there were programs playing around with some kind of backtracking/search-tree approach in the 60s, though I couldn't name a concrete example, with actually useful ones in the late 60s.

Again, let me emphasize that these implementations would have little similarity with how search-trees are used today to play games - the machines were just too slow, and there was too little memory, to do this on the same scale as it is done today.

Comment: The left hand wall algorithm is itself an example of a backtracking depth first search.

Comment: @JeremyP I disagree, the left-hand rule doesn't need a stack for internal state, which is what you need for backtracking/dfs.

Comment: I don't see that the Ross 'robot arm' required a search tree. The maze was simple, and only one level of backtracking was needed.  At any junction, if you take the path that encounters a dead end, then back up to the junction and take the other path.  There was a 'memory' aspect which recorded the route as a series of left/right decisions, such that on restarting the maze, no mistakes would be made.

Comment: The Samuel's checker playing program - debuted in 1959 - used alpha-beta pruning and was in development since 1949 and apparently Samuel was instrumental in developing the IBM 701 instruction set to facilitate his checkers program - see [Arthur Samuel – Biography, History and Inventions](https://history-computer.com/arthur-samuel-biography-history-and-inventions/)

Comment: @dirkt If you view the maze as a tree, which it is topologically, the left wall rule is clearly a depth first search with backtracking. You don't need a stack as such, you just need to know how to get back from each node to its parent.

Comment: @JeremyP yes, I know. The difference is that in a maze, the complete search tree has a representation (the maze itself). For search trees like the ones you use for chess or go, this is not the case. Nor you can calculate the parent node from the current node. So that's fundamentally different. So "I can travel a concrete representation of a search tree with the left-hand rule" doesn't buy you anything for the kind of search trees the OP was asking about.

Comment: Note - I have not actually made it a requisite that the tree or part of it be stored, I just left that undecided to allow 'interesting' other designs to be posted.  My unavoidable error was in mentioning storage of the search-tree or how much of it had been generated so far.  To make this question truly correct, maybe I should make it a requisite that the search-tree or how much of it had been generated so far,  be stored.  I think it's wiser to leave it as it is.

Comment: @infomtn Then don't mention "search tree" at all if you are after examples that actually don't use a search tree... the most important takeaway here is "you don't need a search tree implementation to have something solve a maze, or play tic-tac-toe, or chess". And the ways of doing those things have a big variation in complexity, so the question "what was the first one" then becomes even more useless.

Comment: @dirkt Actually, there's no reason you couldn't make a search tree exactly like a maze for chess or go. All you'd need is a pointer from each node back to its parent. Conceptually the search tree for game like chess is exactly like a maze, it's just that you can only realise a very small proportion of it in memory at once.

Comment: @JeremyP - You typed - "you can only realise a very small proportion of it in memory at once" - I'm surprised with todays machines "only realise a very small proportion of it in memory at once"- That got me thinking, what if you somehow made that maze a 3D-Maze ( or other multidimensional-maze ), could you "realise a higher proportion of it in memory at once", I assume the answer would be no. - Also. I wonder if when I type a 3D-Maze ( or other multidimensional-maze ) for chess, would that be the same thing as a 3D-Search-Tree ( or other Multidimensional-Search-Tree )

Comment: Just to add, what about connecting 'search-trees' to other 'search-trees', via nodes, to make Multidimensional-Search-Trees, for solving other things ( don't know ), unless that could also apply to chess

Comment: @infomtn It doesn't matter how many dimensions you use, the limiting factor is the number of nodes you can store. In a chess game, even on the first move, you have twenty choices. Each of those choices has twenty possible responses. If we say each move has ten possible options on average (don't know if that is true but it seems reasonable), to create a whole tree for a twenty move game needs 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 nodes, well beyond the capacity of any existing computer.

Answer (score 3):

Samuel's checker playing program - debuted in 1959 - used alpha-beta pruning and was in development since 1949 and apparently Samuel was instrumental in developing the IBM 701 instruction set to facilitate his checkers program - see ["Arthur Samuel – Biography, History and Inventions"](https://history-computer.com/arthur-samuel-biography-history-and-inventions/).

Comment: It'd be interesting to know more about what influence this had on the instruction set.  The article, alas, is silent on that.

Comment: *"Because his checker work was one of the earliest examples of non-numerical 
computation, Samuel greatly influenced the instruction set of early IBM 
computers. The logical instructions of these computers were put in at his 
instigation and were quickly adopted by all computer designers, because they 
are useful for most non-numerical computation"* -- [Stanford memorial resolution for Samuel](https://web.archive.org/web/20110526195107/http://histsoc.stanford.edu/pdfmem/SamuelA.pdf), in the wayback machine,

Comment: @another-dave - huh, very interesting - and here I thought the logical operations were put in because, you know, binary logic: why not?  But it definitely is the case that early computers were primarily for _numerical_ calculation (ballistic tables and so forth - even early accounting applications probably had no more need of special boolean instructions - you could do everything you needed with conditional jumps).  (Or so I see it now.)  Thanks!  (Oh, and also early computers were not necessarily _binary_ based so it wasn't obvious to them I guess!)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with noughts and crosses.

Some sort of 'first' seems to have been awarded to Donald Davies (who later went on to [invent packet switching](https://internethalloffame.org/inductees/donald-davies)).  He reportedly had a relay-based noughts and crosses game in 1949; [this article](https://historictech.com/donald-davies-and-the-first-artificial-intelligence-machine-of-1949/) reproduces a paper with a picture of a decision tree.

It appears it set of some sort of craze for such things in the electronics literature and popular press.

---

Since I'd mentioned seeing a simple noughts-and-crosses machine in my childhood:

I now think it was the machine described in the [September 1965](https://worldradiohistory.com/UK/Practical-Electronics/60s/Practical-Electronics-1965-09.pdf) edition of *Practical Electronics*, pages 806 to 812.  The logic is implemented purely on switches.

I have yet to read and understand the logic. At first glance, there's some curious stuff about how if the machine fails to announce a move, you need to rotate a switch to unstick it.

Comment: A decision tree isn't a search tree.  There's no search being made: the tree is precalculated.  (I actually implemented tic-tac-toe this way in FORTRAN II, my first program ever, when I was in junior high. I had the entire decision tree drawn on multiple sheets of paper and I just coded it straight. I've been embarrassed about it for many many years now.)

Comment: @davidbak - are you saying that Davies' machine used a precomputed decision tree?  It wasn't clear to me from the reproduced book page whether that was talking about something wired into the machine. I agree that the *PE* machine did - maybe I should not have muddied the waters there.

Comment: I do not know.  But later in the article he is quoted as saying "There seems to be no possibility, with electronic machines as at present contemplated, of analysing any game of reasonable size completely."  Note: he speaks of "**completely**".  Tic-tac-toe can be analyzed completely in a few pages (as I said, I did it!)  He talks of the mini-max algorithm - but that can be done by hand for a game like tic-tac-toe (I refuse to call it "noughts and crosses").  I think the idea of a runtime search of a large tree came later with programmable computers, not relay systems.  (As for Checkers.)